# FireDAC SQLite encryption on OS X

Tags: sqlite, delphi, encryption, c++builder

Trying to port a working Win32 project including SQLite data encryption to OS X, I found a problem.

The project was developed with RAD Studio Berlin 10.1 and C++ Builder personality. It includes the component FDSQLiteSecurity. The problem occurs also using the Delphi personality.

The unit contains:

```
TDFConnection *FDConnection1;
TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink *FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink1;
TFDSQLiteSecurity *FDSQLiteSecurity1;
```

Here is my piece of code:

```
String DatabaseName, Password;
...
#ifdef WIN32
  DatabaseName = "C:\\...\\MyDB.db";
#endif
#ifdef MACOS
  DatabaseName = "/.../MyDB.db";
#endif
Password = "mypassword";
...
FDConnection1->Params->Values["Database"] = DatabaseName;
FDSQLiteSecurity1->Database = DatabaseName;
FDSQLiteSecurity1->Password = Password;
FDConnection1->Params->Values["Password"] = Password;    
FDConnection1->Connected = true;
...
```

On OS X the connection raises EAccessViolation.

The program works normally by removing the security management lines, using non-encrypted files.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Comment: There is no information available other than EAccessViolation? No error message, no stack trace, not anything? What does the debugger tell you if you set a breakpoint at `FDConnection1->Params-Values["Database"] = DatabaseName;` and then evaluate `FDSQLLiteSecurity` (which it appears should be `FDSQLLiteSecurity1` instead)?

Comment: @Ken, thanks for the answer. Here is more information: 
'Project Test raised exception class EAccessViolation with 'Access violation at address 00132AAA, accessing address 00132AAA''. No more debugging error message reported. The program works up to 'FDConnection1->Connected = true;'. Then the exception occurs. At this point the stack reports 'Process is not accessible'. Evaluating FDSQLLiteSecurity1 before raising exception, its properties are properly set.

The name of component is FDSQLLiteSecurity1, it was just a typing refuse (corrected).

Comment: Can you [edit] your post and put that information in the question itself, where it belongs, instead of buried in comments?

Answer (score 0):

Your used typename seems to have a typo:
T***DF***Connection *FDConnection1 must be T***FD***Connection *FDConnection1